# Copy ARP table to an array

Tags: c, linux, networking, arp

I've been trying to figure out the best way to copy Linux ARP table into an array, I just need IP and MAC address. I have tried copying the /proc/net/arp file, but I do not find it the best way to do it, I read there might appear other entries beside ARP (IPv6 or sth). I am not sure! Is there any other option to get local ARP table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ip neighbor list` command from [iproute2](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/iproute2) uses a [netlink](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/7/netlink) socket to query the kernel about the neighbour information.

It is recommended to use the [libnetlink](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/3/libnetlink) from the same iproute2 package to access this information.

Comment: Is there an example somewhere to do this with libnetlink from a c program?